# Can I make class accessible by the entire project?

Tags: java, class

I am making a small application, for which I want an error system.
Just a really simple window that pops up, with the specified error and exit number.
For that I have made a "Message"  class, that makes a JOptionPane with the message, that all works like a charm. But I have to import and create the Message object in every class in order to access it. Is there a way around this, because I don't feel like having to create a Message object in every single class that could potentially have a specified error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you making it in swing, if yes, you can put type of pop up window, there is alert, critical, and some other types. And class always can be accessed from the entire project. You just have to instantiate it.

Comment: Why do your require a separate message class?? Why not just use JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Your message", "Error code", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); .. What is wrong with this???

Comment: @WeareBorg Well, because I want to be able to save a file with the error message as well, something that takes up quite a lot of space if you have to do that every time...

Comment: Then call that function which saves the file. This is a weird question to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say is it a method but if it is then you could make static method (no need to create new class then) and then use it like `Message.method(message, error code);`. Or even add `import static` what gives you ability to do something like this: `method(message, error code);`.